# Найти максимальный периметр

Tags: c

Есть четыре рейки, из которых можно сделать прямоугольную рамку. При этом не обязательно, чтобы все рейки были использованы полностью или частично.

Можно разрезать любую рейку на 2 или более частей, но нельзя соединять рейки или их части для использования полученной склейки в качестве какой-либо стороны рамки.

Напишите программу, определяющую максимальный периметр прямоугольной рамки, которую можно сделать из четырех реек заданных размеров.

Первая строка ввода содержит четыре целых числа a, b, c, d в неубывающем порядке
(1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d ≤ 1000) — размеры реек.

В первой строке необходимо вывести одно целое число — максимальный периметр рамки.

Пример ввода
5 7 12 15

Пример вывода
34

**Нельзя использовать циклы**

Код не рабочий. Не знаю как исправить.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{int a,b,c,d,s,n,m,z,y;
int k;
scanf("%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
s = b*2 + d;
n = a*2 + c * 2;
m = c + d;
z = b + 2*c;
if (s >= n && s >= m && s >=z ){
    k = s;
    printf("%d",k);
}
else if(m >= s && m >= n && m >= z ){
    k = m;
    printf("%d",k);
}
else if (z >= s && z >= m && z > =n ){
    k = z;
    printf("%d", k);
}

else{
    k = n;
    printf("%d", k);
}
}
```

Comment: А что делает код?

Comment: ищет периметр. В условии написано, что вводятся данные в неубывающем порядке. Соответственно, идет проверка на нули. Я не понимаю по какой формуле находить максимальный периметр

Comment: У вас трудности с алгоритмом или с языком программирования?

Comment: с алгоритмом. По сути я не могу подобрать формулы и условия для нахождения максимального периметра.

Comment: Проверки на 0 вообще не нужзны.

Comment: Условия запрещают нули явно. Не надо тратить на них силы.

Comment: исправил код, но он тоже не проходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlexeyTen: А я уже проснулся и пишу всякую ересь ))

Алгоритм: по-всякому раскладываем 4 стороны `x x y y` по 4 рейкам `a b c d` и считаем где получится наибольший периметр

Вот псевдокод:

```lua
local function even(x)
   -- округляем вниз до чётного числа
   return x - x%2
end

local function perimeter(a,b,c,d)
   return
      math.max(
         -- -, -, -, xxyy
         even(d),
         -- -, -, x, xyy
         2*c + even(d-c),
         -- -, -, xx, yy
         even(c) + even(d),
         -- -, -, xy, xy
         2*c,
         -- -, x, x, yy
         2*b + even(d),
         -- -, x, y, xy
         2*math.min(b+c, d),
         -- x, x, y, y
         2*a + 2*c
      )
end

print(perimeter(5, 7, 12, 15))  --> 34
```

Внимательный читатель заметит, что функция `even` может вернуть 0, и получается, что этот алгоритм иногда порождает прямоугольники с нулевыми сторонами, которые нужно бы отбросить.
Но к счастью, в данном случае не нужно, потому что если мы получили прямоугольник со сторонами `0` и `y`, то его всегда можно преобразовать в прямоугольник со сторонами `1` и `y-1` с точно таким же периметром.
А вдруг `y=1`, и тогда `y-1=0`?  Такой прямоугольник не будет наибольшим, ведь всегда будет доступен квадрат со стороной `a` (как минимум 1) и периметром не меньше 4.

Я почему-то подумал, что длины сторон прямоугольника тоже должны быть целыми числами, но теперь вгляделся в условие и не увидел такого требования.  Например, из реек `1 1 5 10` можно собрать прямоугольник со сторонами `5` и `2.5` и периметром 15.  Тогда нужно функцию `even` заменить на возвращающую `x`.

Comment: Первая альтернатива никогда не реализуется.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - да, пятая всегда лучше первой, а седьмая лучше четвёртой.  Но я оставлю так для читабельности (чтобы легче было убедиться, что перебраны все возможные варианты и никто не забыт)

Comment: А первая не соответствует ли случаю 1,2,3,400? Или я неправильно понимаю расклады?

Comment: @MBo, `1, 2, 3, 400` -> `2, 2, 200, 200`. Что лучше чем первая.

Comment: Да, действительно, и мелочь пригодится